# How come importing methods from a class from a different file won't work for me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, methods

I've been trying to figure out why importing methods from a class from a different file won't work for me.

I made a simplified version where, in the end, I want to print numbers from 0 to 9 with a 1 second delay between. Instead, nothing happens. I have three files, print.py, generate.py, and main.py (main code that I am running). generate.py calls for a method from a class in print.py, and main.py calls for a method from a class in generate.py

In print.py, I have

```
import time
class printer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def printStuff(n):
        print(n)
```

In generate.py, I have

```
from print import printer
class generator(printer):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    binaryNumbers =[
        int('11111100', 2),
        int('01100000', 2),
        int('11011010', 2),
        int('11110010', 2),
        int('01100110', 2),
        int('10110110', 2),
        int('10111110', 2),
        int('11100000', 2),
        int('11111110', 2),
        int('11110110', 2) ]
    def displayNum(n):
        number=binaryNumbers[n]
        printer.printStuff(number)
```

In main.py, I have

```
import time
from generate import generator
def countUp():
    for n in range(10):
        generator.displayNum(n)
        time.sleep(1)
try:
    while 1:
        countUp()
```

Does anyone see a syntax error that I am missing? Thank you.

I am using repl to run the code. I am not getting any error message. Rather, nothing happens and it waits for me to run another piece of code. I also tried adding an except Keyboard Interrupt: and getting rid of the "try-except" altogether and I am still unable to get it to work.

Comment: Could you add the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: You have a `try` without `except` or `finally`.

Comment: I am not getting any error message. Rather, it waits for me to run another code. I also added an except KeyboardInterrupt: and tried getting rid of the try-except and I am still unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrospect your goal. If you want to use OOP, you have to **get a object** instead of using classmethod.
Your main code should like this:

```
import time
import logging

from generate import generator


def countUp():
    for n in range(10):
        g = generator()
        g.displayNum(n)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while 1:
            countUp()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

print.py like this:

```
import time


class printer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    # I thought you want to add a instance method, so I add `self`
    def printStuff(self, n):
        print(n)
```

and generate.py like this:

```
from print import printer


class generator(printer):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    binaryNumbers = [
        int('11111100', 2),
        int('01100000', 2),
        int('11011010', 2),
        int('11110010', 2),
        int('01100110', 2),
        int('10110110', 2),
        int('10111110', 2),
        int('11100000', 2),
        int('11111110', 2),
        int('11110110', 2)]

    # I thought you want to add a instance method, so I add `self`
    def displayNum(self, n):
        number = self.binaryNumbers[n]
        p = printer()
        p.printStuff(number)
```

Although you can run this code, I suggest rename print.py another name because it may lead to more errors you cannot image.